# static vs shared library security

Tags: c++, security, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Considering a library that provides a function that accepts a password or a license key or sensitive data, is there any difference in terms of security between a shared and a static library?

is it possible to "sniff" the calls performed on a shared library? or to replace the original shared library with a fake shared library and "print" all the arguments passed to a function call to that library?

Comment: It's possible to sniff it, but why would someone want to sniff their own password, key, or data? If you're asking if you can process data on a machine and keep it secure from that machine's operator/owner (with typical hardware on typical operating systems), the answer is no.

Comment: I was thinking of releasing software based on a library that requires a license key. By redistributing this software, my license key could become available.

Comment: Follow the library license. If it requires you to keep the key secret but also distribute it, it's asking you to do the impossible. Generally such keys are not intended to be kept secret. If a user stole the key and used it in another program, the key would serve its intended purpose of making it easy for the library author to prove the thief didn't purchase the key (since you did, and the thief isn't you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed replacing the shared library is an easy way to capture the key. However, putting a breakpoint and capturing the key in the running application when you link the library statically isn't hard either. So as a library developer you need to live with it - there's no good solution for this problem. Methods to counteract stealing keys and using the "pirated" versions of your library are mainly non-technical - track users and deny support to those who are not registered, provide updates via restricted area on your web site etc.

Comment: if the library is static and included in the final binary, you could strip all the symbols... can you still set a breakpoint in that case? how can the debugger know where the function name is in the stripped binary?

Comment: @Sdra hackers don't rely on symbols when doing the job. It's probably easy to take your library alone (not linked into the product) and see what function goes where. As a person that has some experience with code analysis I can say that it's not hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

In general yes it's possible to replace a shared library with your own version that provides the same interface, in linux you can set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for example to tell it where to look for libraries, and in windows you can put DLLs in the search path.

However if you can do that you can replace the main program too with an altered version of the original so there aren't really too many differences in security other than the difficulty of intercepting the data.